# How to get row of particular position of recycler view in android?

Tags: android

In my application I need to get a complete row of recycler view (becuase I want to get some view of that row) of a particular position.I searched we can get position by method getAdapterPosition().Now after getting position via this method I want to get complete row of that position.How can I achieve it?

Edit: I have some view on every row and I have set onclick listner on buttons in click of that I want get complete row or top layout (parent layout).What I understand is when on click is called it return parent view on which button is wrapped but not complete row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got solution to this problem now. First get the recycler view in adapter using below method in adapter class

```
   @Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
}
```

and on click event use below code

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(getAdapterPosition());
```

and then cast the holder to the actual object as mentioned below

```
MessageViewHolder messageViewHolder = (MessageViewHolder) holder;
```

Congrats!! now you have a complete row of that particular position. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I used one class for getting views(and Click and Long clicks too)

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }


    public interface ClickListener {

        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

}
```

and to use  this

/**
         *  Recycler view item click handler
         */

```
rvDraft.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(),
                    rvDraft, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
    // click operation

                }

                @Override
                public void onLongClick(View view, final int position) {

                    Dialogs dialog = new Dialogs();
                    dialog.showAlertForAction(getActivity(), getString(R.string.are_u_sure_want_to_delete), new AlertInterface() {
                        @Override
                        public void buttonYesClick() {

                           // long press operation

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void buttonNoClick() {

                        }
                    });

                }
            }));
```

Hope this will help you .

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable `View selectedView`. In your custom `ViewHolder` class, assuming the row item to be a LinearLayout set add the following lines

```
rowItemLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_item);

rowItemLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         selectedView = rowItemLayout;
         ..
    }
});
```

Now you can fetch that view using

```
public View getSelectedView() {
            return selectedView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
getBindingAdapterPosition(view);
getAbsoluteAdapterPosition() ;
getchildAdapterPosition(view);
```